# Google App Script - Save the sheet file Id created from my sheet file template

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

thank you for the time you will take to resolve my issue !

I am not sure that Google app script allows to do what I need.
Could you please tell me if it is possible?
If yes, do you have already a script code to do it?

I have created a file which I have shared it with others colleagues (in a shared drive), and it is used as a "template".

When a colleague creates a copy of it, I would like that the script to give me the new Google sheet id created from the model and saved this id in my Google sheet dashboard?

Is it possible with appscript?

Thanks a lot and have a good day !

Comment: What would keep your colleague from just copying with google drive without using a script at all?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that reports the id automatically when any user make a copy of your template (from the Google Drive interface, for example, or by opening your template and choosing File | Make Copy)?  Or are you looking for a script you can run on behalf of your colleagues, that both creates the copy and records the id (this is what Cooper's answer does)?

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. But it is not really that I would like.  I would like a solution that mentioned by Aaron in his first case. A solution which reports the id automatically when any user make a copy of my template. The id must be saved in my google sheet dashboArd. Is it possible?

Comment: I put the id in column 1 of a sheet name Dashboard since you have provided no information regarding your dashboard.

Comment: Thank you Cooper. it runs but not as I would like.  Is it possible to modify the content of this script procedure, in order that the file could be copied only with the action of the user via the google sheet menu "File/copy File" and after, via a trigger as "onEdit", the script stored in the model sheet file, copied the id of the copy file in the dashboard file. I hope that my explanations are clear ! And thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy Spreadsheet and Save Id

```
function copySpreadsheetAndSaveId() {
  const fileId = "fileid";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive():
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy().getId());//appends the id to the bottom of column one in the sheeet named Dashboard.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to be able to open the Spreadsheet then you can't restrict them copying it by script only

I can think of a couple of workarounds:

#### Workaround 1:

Make the Spreadsheet private, and create a web app which runs as you but is accessible by other users. On `doGet()`, create a copy of the Spreadsheet and share it with the email returned from [`Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()):

```js
function doGet() {
  // Check if security policy gets email address:
  const user = Session.getActiveUser()
  if (!user.getEmail()) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Unable to retrieve user.')
  }

  const ss = DriveApp.getFileById("template-spreadsheet-id")
  const newFile = ss.makeCopy().addEditor(user)

  const html = `File copied, click <a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${newFile.getId()}/edit">here</a> to open.`
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
}
```

Pros:

- Should work for anyone within the same domain as you
- You can directly retrieve the ID on copy and save it to your database

Cons:

- Security policy might stop you being able to get the user
- What's to stop them from just copying the copy?

#### Workaround 2:

If you're an admin user, you could use the [Drive Audit Activity API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive) to check for domain-wide copy events of a given file ID. It's a bit more involved and assumes you have a client set up in GCP but will have a bigger catch-radius than the first workaround, and also doesn't involve restricting access to the template or creating a Web App:

```js
function getAuditLog() {
  const baseUrl = "https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive"
  const apiKey = "api-key-obtained-from-gcp"

  const params + `eventName=copy&key=${apiKey}`

  const headers = {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`,
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${baseUrl}?${params}`, {
    "method": "get",
    "headers": headers"
  })

  const responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
}
```

You'll then have to process the response. `responseData` contains an `items` key which is an array of `copy` events in the audit report:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#reports#activities",
  "etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "admin#reports#activity",
      "id": {
        "time": "2022-01-21T10:03:12.793Z",
        "uniqueQualifier": "-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "applicationName": "drive",
        "customerId": "xxxxxxx"
      },
      "etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx\"",
      "actor": {
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "profileId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "ipAddress": "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000",
      "events": [
        {
          "type": "access",
          "name": "copy",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "primary_event",
              "boolValue": false
            },
            {
              "name": "billable",
              "boolValue": true
            },
            {
              "name": "old_value",
              "multiValue": [
                "Spreadsheet Template File Name"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "new_value",
              "multiValue": [
                "Copy of Spreadsheet Template File Name"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "doc_id",
              "value": "new-spreadsheet-id"
            },
            {
              "name": "doc_type",
              "value": "spreadsheet"
            },
            {
              "name": "is_encrypted",
              "boolValue": false
            },
            {
              "name": "doc_title",
              "value": "Copy of Spreadsheet Template File Name"
            },
            {
              "name": "visibility",
              "value": "private"
            },
            {
              "name": "actor_is_collaborator_account",
              "boolValue": false
            },
            {
              "name": "owner",
              "value": "user@example.com"
            },
            {
              "name": "owner_is_shared_drive",
              "boolValue": false
            },
            {
              "name": "owner_is_team_drive",
              "boolValue": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

You will have to filter out the reponse from here, however. For each element in the `items` array, the `events` key contains the information you will need to look for:

- `old_value` is the original template spreadsheet's name
- `doc_id` is the ID of the new spreadsheet

`items.actor` is the email of the person that completed the action.

#### References:

- [Example Audit request using the Try this API feature](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22applicationName%22%3A%22drive%22%2C%22eventName%22%3A%22copy%22%7D&apix=true)